# Python tk entry box not active until window deselected

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

I have a small Tk-based application that uses a standard layout of a window, defined in **init**. For one of the submenu items, I need to temporarily create a small form, which I remove after it is successfully submitted. I do this on the fly with the code in start_make_canvas in the mcve below:

```
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

NONE=0
TAGGING=1
MAKECANVAS=4
TAGS=["some text","some more text"]
PICS=["c:/users/rob/desktop/camera.jpg","c:/users/rob/desktop/fridge.jpg"]

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)             
        self.master=master
        self.mode=NONE
        self.init_window()
        self.start_tagging()
    def start_tagging(self):
        if self.photo is not None:
            self.photo.destroy()
            self.photo=None
        messagebox.showinfo("Start tagging")
        self.mode=TAGGING
        self.configure_buttons()
        self.show_pic()
    def init_window(self):
        menubar=Menu(self.master)
        menu=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menu.add_command(label="Start tagging",command=self.start_tagging)
        menu.add_command(label="Make canvas",command=self.start_make_canvas)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Tag",menu=menu)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1) #take full space of root window
        self.photo=None
        self.tag_trk={}
        row=1
        for tag in TAGS:
            self.tag_trk[tag]=IntVar()
            Checkbutton(self,text=tag,variable=self.tag_trk[tag]).place(x=500,y=10+20*row)
            row+=1
        self.tag_count=StringVar()
        self.button1_label=StringVar()
        self.btn1=Button(self,textvariable=self.button1_label,command=self.button1_click)
        self.btn1.place(x=10,y=495)
        self.max_score=StringVar()
    def configure_buttons(self):
        if self.mode==NONE:
            self.button1_label.set("Tag")
        elif self.mode==TAGGING:
            self.button1_label.set("Next")
        elif self.mode==MAKECANVAS:
            self.button1_label.set("Make")
    def button1_click(self):
        if self.mode==TAGGING:
            self.show_pic()
        elif self.mode==MAKECANVAS:
            # do some things here
            for e in self.form: e.destroy()
            self.mode=NONE
            self.configure_buttons()
        elif self.mode==NONE:
            self.start_tagging()
    def show_pic(self):
        if self.photo is not None:
            self.photo.destroy()
        img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(PICS)))
        self.photo=tkinter.Label(self,image=img,borderwidth=0)
        self.photo.image=img
        self.photo.place(x=15,y=5)
    def start_make_canvas(self):
        if self.photo is not None:
            self.photo.destroy()
            self.photo=None
        self.mode=MAKECANVAS
        self.form=[]
        e=Label(self,text='Max score')
        e.place(x=80,y=200)
        self.form.append(e)
        e=Entry(self,textvariable=self.max_score,width=20)
        e.place(x=180,y=200)
        self.form.append(e)
        self.form[1].focus_set()
        self.configure_buttons()

def target_tags():
    global root
    root=tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("700x570")
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
    app=Window(root)
    root.mainloop()

def on_closing():
    global root
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_tags()
```

The problem occurs after selecting "Make Canvas" from the menu - the form creation works just fine, except that the newly created Entry elements are not active when first created: I cannot see an insertion cursor, and typed text does not go into the entry. When I select a different window and the reselect my application window, all is fine. Is there a method I need to call after I create the form for mainloop to recognize that there are new bits to be looking after?

Note: in creating the mcve, I found that the messagebox in start_tagging was necessary to recreate the problem. Without it, everything works from the get-go. With it, the checkboxes that are created initially work fine, but the new entry box doesn't (until the window is unselected/reselected).

Comment: Does this happen in response to a user action or at startup? Specifically, did your app window have focus before this? Could you include a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, the form is created as a direct result of a menu selection from the same app window. I can try to work up an MCVE if there's no immediately obvious cause for this behavior.

Comment: The menu does seen to be relevant 'cuz it's technically a "top-level" widget.

Comment: Without an MCVE, I can only keep guessing 'cuz from what I can see, your code should work as written. That's why they are required at SO: otherwise, you never really know if the code that you gave is the culprit or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made an mcve (now above), and it indeed helped to narrow down the source of the problem, which appears to be the use of a modal dialog (messagebox) during the start of the program.

Comment: `import tkinter; from tkinter import *` is problematic: in Py2, `tkinter` has an attribute of the same name that overwrites the module variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `Entry` control looks as if it hasn't been fully initialized yet: I cannot even click on the control and input something into it, it doesn't react. It goes to normal if I Alt-Tab out of the app and back in. **Using `focus_force()` helps as a workaround** (it's justified in this case since it's done as a response to user's affirmative action).

This could as well be a bug in Tk, or some additional step is required after `.place()` that [place manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/place.htm) "forgot" to mention. (With `ttk.Entry`, it's just the same, so not a case of obsolete code.) You can ask @ tcl-core@lists.sourceforge.net about this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it some more. I confirmed that the focus_force method works, which is good enough for me right now.